# How i can create multiple random paragraph elements with javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to create multiple paragraphs with random text using the values in this array:

```
var values = ["Carl","Maria","Joseph","Tatiane","Dayanne"];
```

But honestly I do not know how to do that; this is my code...

```
var paragraph = document.createElement("p");
paragraph.innerText = "random string";
document.body.appendChild(paragraph);
```

I need to create 35 paragraphs ...

Answer (score 0):

innerText is a quirky nonstandard property that IE introduced. It is highly recommended to instead use the standard, quicker, more reliable textContent instead - see http://perfectionkills.com/the-poor-misunderstood-innerText

You can get a random element from an array using `arr[Math.floor(Math.random() * arr.length)]`:

```js
const words = ["Carl","Maria","Joseph","Tatiane","Dayanne"];

Array.from({ length: 35 })
  .forEach(() => {
    const randomText = words[Math.floor(Math.random() * words.length)];
    document.body
      .appendChild(document.createElement("p"))
      .textContent = randomText;
  });
```

Comment: Thanks, im using firefox, internet explorer, and chrome, i will try, wait

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
    var values = ["Carl", "Maria", "Joseph", "Tatiane", "Dayanne"];
    var total = 35;

    for (count = 1; count <= total; count++) {
        // Get random index within the array bounds
        var randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * values.length);

        // Get value in the array that corresponds to the random index.
        var value = values[randomIndex];

        // Create the <p> tag.
        var p = document.createElement('p');
        p.innerText = value;
        document.body.appendChild(p);
    }
</script>
```